# Two smooth bounded connected domains in $\Bbb R^d$ with the same boundary are identical

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $\Omega_1,\Omega_2\subset\Bbb R^d$ be two connected opens such that $\overline{\Omega_1}$ and $\overline{\Omega_2}$ are smooth bounded connected manifolds with boundary. Then I suspect that if $\partial\Omega_1=\partial\Omega_2$, then $\Omega_1=\Omega_2$, however, I don't see how to prove this. Is the correct to solution to put some normal vector field on the boundaries and use that?

Comment: What about the upper and lower hemispheres of a sphere? Specifically you can write $S^2 = D^2\cup S^1 \cup D^2$, where one copy of $D^2$ is a disk "stretched" to a sheet covering the upper hemisphere, another is a similar disk but in the lower hemisphere.

Here the $=$ is "homeomorphic", but if you decompose $S^2$ in such a way you should have the lower/upper parts having the same boundary, but being distinct.

Comment: In the question I required the manifolds to have codimension $0$.

Comment: Did you remember to post that?  I don't currently see that requirement.

Additonally, the "stretched copies of $D^2$" should have interior of dimension $2$, so if I'm understanding the concept of codimension right they should have codimension $0$, right?

Comment: The fact that each manifold contains an open of $\Bbb R^d$ implies that they must be if codimension $0$.

Comment: The important point here is the difference between a sphere and Euclidean space. Yes, in the sphere there are two distinct domains with the same boundary, but Euclidean space is not a sphere.

Comment: This looks like something that follows from the triviality of singular homology  in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: I also get that sense -- however, I don't immediately see precisely how we can apply it. Maybe we should start by considering the components of $\partial\Omega$?

Answer (score 3):

Each $\Omega_i$ defines an element $c_i$ of the simplicial chain group $C_{d}(R^d)$ (just triangulate them; WLOG, triangulations agree on the common boundary). Now, orient each $\Omega_i$ so that the induced orientations of the boundary are the same. Then the chain $c= c_1 - c_2$ is a cycle. If $\Omega_1\ne \Omega_2$, there is a point $p\in \Omega_1- \Omega_2$; then the intersection number between $c$ and the 0-cycle $p$ is $1$. Hence, $c$ defines a nonzero element of $H_d(R^d)$. But $R^d$ is contractible, so $H_d(R^d)=0$. A contradiction. Consider reading "Differential Topology" by Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: Does *Differential Topology* contain a proof of the fact that $\Omega_i$ can be triangulated so as to share a common boundary?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine: No, it does not. But in fact, you do not need a triangulation: Guillemin and Pollack work without introducing singular homology. All what you need is no notice that there is an abstract smooth oriented manifold $Z$ obtained by  gluing copies $\Omega'_1, \Omega'_2$ of $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ along their common boundary and a continuous map $f: Z\to R^n$ which sends $\Omega'_i\to\Omega_i$ and such that some point $p\in R^n$ lies in $f(\Omega_1')- f(\Omega_2')$.