# Two smooth bounded domains in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the same boundary are equal

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-topology

Given two bounded smooth open subsets of the plane, can I say that if their boundary are equal then they are equal ?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297078/two-smooth-bounded-connected-domains-in-bbb-rd-with-the-same-boundary-are-id) received a positive answer under a connectedness assumption on both sets, but I would like to know if this assumption can be removed.

Edit: by smooth set I mean a set whose interior and boundary are locally the epigraph and the graph of a smooth (say $C^{\infty}$) function.

Edit: I guess the result reduces to proving that for every connected component $E$ of the first set, there is a unique connected component $F$ of the second set such that $\partial E=\partial F$. One could then conclude using the answer to the linked question.

Comment: ... and *smooth function* means?  $C^\infty$ ?

Comment: Does the answer to the linked question actually use connectedness? (My homology theory is very rusty, so I am not sure whether it is actually used in there or not.) I would think that the regularity of the boundary is more important here than connectedness, especially given that [connected counterexamples exist without the smoothness assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada).

Comment: @GEdgar yes. However, if the result holds for $C^{\infty}$, I would expect it to hold also for continuous ...

Comment: @WillieWong I really do not understand the tools used in the answer to the linked question. I would also guess that the regularity of the boundary is the only thing that really matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that for smooth domain you mean a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ whose boundary is a smooth curve. Then, the answer is no.

Let $D_r$ be the open disk of radius $r$ centred in the origin and $S_r$ be its boundary.

Let $U = \mathrm{int}(D_2\setminus D_1)$, where int denotes the interior. In other words you have $$U=\{(x, y): x^2+y^2\in(1, 4)\}\,.$$ Clearly $U$ is a open smooth region and its boundary is $S_1\cup S_2$.

Now, consider $V = D_1\cup U$, that is $$V=\{(x, y): x^2+y^2\in[0,1)\cup(1, 4)\}\,.$$ Again, this is an open smooth region and its boundary is $S_1\cup S_2$.

$U$ and $V$ are bounded, smooth, and with the same boundary. Yet, $U\neq V$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Indeed, I should have been more precise in my definition of smooth set. I just edited my question to clarify. I think that with this definition of smooth set the set $V$ you introduce is not smooth.

Comment: @Rom1P if you mean topological boundary then ECL has right, two domains may have the same boundary without being homeomorphic. In the case you mean _geometric_ boundary then the circle of radius $1$ is not a component of the boundary despite it belongs to $\overline{V}$. What do you mean with boundary here?

Comment: My original question comes from geometric measure theory. I reformulated it in a way I hoped to be clear and simple, but indeed I think the topological boundary is not really what I was looking for. For those interested, the result I wanted to get is as follows: if $E$ and $F$ are two bounded sets of finite perimeter in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then if their essential boundary are equal (modulo $\mathcal{H}^{d-1}$), the two sets are equivalent (modulo a Lebesgue negligible set). This is essentially contained in [this paper](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=1435-9855&vol=3&iss=1&rank=2)

Answer (score 1):

Another example (at least for the topological boundary).
Begin with a countable set of numbers $r_k \in (1,2)$ that cluster only at $1$ and $2$.  The boundary set consists of circles centered at the origin with these radii.  The two sets $E, F$ consist of alternating annuli.  The annuli get narrower and narrower as we approach radius $1$ or radius $2$.  The topological boundary consists of these circles, together with the circles of radii $1$ and $2$.  Does the geometric boundary consist only of these circles, without the two extreme circles?

[image: annuli]

There is a $C^\infty$ function that vanishes on these circles, and is alternately positive and negative on the annuli.